# C# на macOS. Как получить содержимое файла?

Tags: c#, .net

Коллеги, подскажите, как можно реализовать функцию, достающую всё содержимое из файла.
Должно получится что-то вроде этого:

```
public static string GetFileContent(string filename) {
    // магия

    return content;
}
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

**Правка:** использовать StreamReader не получается, выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: А почему string? Файл текстовый?

Comment: Принимает на вход имя файла: string. Возвращает содержимое файла: string. Что не так?

Comment: Если это нетекстовый файл, обычно имеет смысл представлять контент как массив байт

Comment: В данном случае я точно знаю, что файл будет текстовый.

Comment: _StreamReader не получается, выдаёт ошибку._ - что за ошибка?

Comment: [File.ReadAllText](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-5.0)

Comment: StreamReader' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: Ну да, нет у него такого конструктора. Посмотрите в документации, какой конструктор есть. А проще и правда `File.ReadAllText`.

Comment: `return File.ReadAllText(filename);` вот и вся магия